# UserControls aren't displayed properly in ListBox when added from Code-behind (C#, WPF)

Tags: c#, wpf, listbox, user-controls

I got a simple `UserControl` that is basically just a Grid with 6 Columns and a bunch of TextBlocks.

**XAML:**

```
<UserControl x:Class="MyApplication.TimeAccountItem"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:MyApplication"
             mc:Ignorable="d">
    <UserControl.Resources>
        <local:TimeSpanConverter x:Key="TimeSpanConverter"/>
        <Style TargetType="TextBlock">
            <Setter Property="FontSize" Value="14"/>
            <Setter Property="Margin" Value="10,5"/>
            <Setter Property="TextAlignment" Value="Center"/>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>
    <Grid>
        <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="48"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="2*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
            <ColumnDefinition Width="*"/>
        </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="0" x:Name="tb_Id" Text="{Binding User, FallbackValue=0}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="1" x:Name="tb_Employee" Text="{Binding Alias, FallbackValue=Employee}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="2" x:Name="tb_Updated" Text="{Binding Updated, StringFormat=dd.MM.yyy, FallbackValue=00.00.0000}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="3" x:Name="tb_Total" Text="{Binding Total, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, FallbackValue=00:00 h}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="4" x:Name="tb_Claimed" Text="{Binding Claimed, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, FallbackValue=00:00 h}"/>
        <TextBlock Grid.Column="5" x:Name="tb_Remaining" Text="{Binding Remaining, Converter={StaticResource TimeSpanConverter}, FallbackValue=00:00 h}"/>
    </Grid>
</UserControl>
```

**CS:**

```
public partial class TimeAccountItem : UserControl
{
    public TimeAccount content { get; set; }

    public OvertimeListBoxItem(TimeAccount timeAccount)
    {
        content = timeAccount;
        this.DataContext = content;  
    }

    public OvertimeListBoxItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

On my MainWindow I got a `ListBox` where I want to "output" those UserControls.

When I do this in XAML everything works fine.

```
<ListBox Height="400" Margin="10,0" HorizontalContentAlignment="Stretch" BorderThickness="0" Name="listbox">
    <local:TimeAccountItem/>
    <local:TimeAccountItem/>
    <local:TimeAccountItem/>
    <local:TimeAccountItem/>
    <local:TimeAccountItem/>
</ListBox>
```

[image: From XAML]

However not from Code-behind

```
foreach (TimeAccount ta in timeAccountList)
{
    listbox.Items.Add(new TimeAccountItem(ta));
}
```

[image: From code-behind]

I hovered one of the Items to show what happens. Already gave my UserControl a fixed Height instead of Auto but this didn't help either.

What am I doing wrong here?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The UserControl constructor with TimeAccount argument is missing an `InitializeComponent` call:

```
public TimeAccountItem(TimeAccount timeAccount)
{
    DataContext = timeAccount;  
    InitializeComponent();
}
```

---

You should however not be doing this at all.

Instead, declare an appropriate ItemTemplate:

```
<ListBox ...>
    <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <local:TimeAccountItem/>
        </DataTemplate>
    </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
</ListBox>
```

Then remove the explicit DataContext assignment from the UserControl

```
public partial class TimeAccountItem : UserControl
{
    public TimeAccountItem()
    {
        InitializeComponent();
    }
}
```

and assign a collection of data items instead of UI elements to the ListBox's `ItemsSource` property:

```
listbox.ItemSource = timeAccountList;
```

Comment: You're right. I'm not calling `InitializeComponent` since I forgot to add `: this()` to the parameterized constructor. But yours is a way better solution anyways so thanks a lot!